# Uploading files from srver to artifactory

Tags: bash, shell

I have a local server with some files and each time i run automation these files get updated, i would like to copy these file to a repository in artifactory. The files i have is a zip file

I found ways like CI jenkins integration and a maven artifactory plugin, but i would want something in batch script which i could call in my code.

i'm looking for something like scp <"server_file_path"> <"Location_in the _artifactory"> . I cannot be using the artifactory windows client in my machine. so i need to upload to the artifactory web view path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply :

- use the REST Api
- Upload manually

This thread seems to be related :
[How to upload an artifact to Artifactory / consume it in a build system (Gradle Maven Ant) where the artifact does not have an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536706/how-to-upload-an-artifact-to-artifactory-consume-it-in-a-build-system-gradle)